# Id of gridview shows wrong sequence

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview which has columns (Id,Task,Reward,Time Allotted,Uploader)..I can insert data into the gridview successfully untill page no 13 with taskId 118,but after that the data starts to show up at page no 1 right after TaskId 7.

So the sequence is like ....5,6,7,119,120,121,122,8,9,10.....
So all the new data gets inserted between 7 and 8.Why is that?how can i correct this?

I don;t think this is a code fault but still here is mine:

```
    protected void btnPost_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EasyRozMoney_ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spTasks", con);
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", txtTitle.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Body", txtBody.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Reward", txtRewards.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeAllotted", txtTime.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PosterName", txtPoster.Text);

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        lblStatus.Text = "Task Posted Successfully.";

    }
```

here is the gridview:

```
       <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="936px" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="3" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" style="text-align: center" BackColor="#DEBA84" BorderColor="#DEBA84" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellSpacing="2" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="TaskId" HeaderText="TaskId" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="TaskId" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Body" HeaderText="Body" SortExpression="Body" Visible="false" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Reward" HeaderText="Reward(Rs)" SortExpression="Reward" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="TimeAllotted" HeaderText="Time(Min)" SortExpression="TimeAllotted" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="PosterName" HeaderText="Uploader" SortExpression="PosterName" />
                    <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="Select" Text="Perform Task" ControlStyle-ForeColor="White"  ControlStyle-Font-Bold="true">
               <ControlStyle BackColor="#CC6600" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"></ControlStyle>
                    </asp:ButtonField>
                </Columns>
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#F7DFB5" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#CC6600" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <RowStyle BackColor="#FFF7E7" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFF1D4" />
                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#B95C30" />
                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1E5CE" />
                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#93451F" />
            </asp:GridView>

            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:EasyRozMoney_ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Task]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

My Table in sql is as below:

```
       Create table Task
       (
       TaskId int Identity(1,1),
       Title varchar(100),
       Body varchar(500),
       Reward decimal(4,2),
       TimeAllotted int,
       PosterName varchar(100)
       )
```

my stored procedure :

```
      Create proc spTasks
      @Title varchar(100),
      @Body varchar(500),
      @Reward decimal(4,2),
     @TimeAllotted int,
      @PosterName varchar(100)
      as
       begin
       Insert into Task values(@Title,@Body,@Reward,@TimeAllotted,@PosterName)
       end
```

Comment: Can you share your code which you use to bind your gridview with data?

Comment: use task id datatype (int) and as a primary  key i think you have to use in datatype varchar.

Comment: @NayeemMansoori check my edited question.it clearly states that i made a table with taskid as int datatype

Answer (score 1):

You can change the default sort on your select statement of your data source. If you want recent records to show up in the end: sort by default, if you want them to display first in your grid: sort by descending order.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:EasyRozMoney_ConnectionString %>" 
 SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Task] ORDER BY TASKID"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

On a note, you should use select '*' only in test cases. In real world scenarios, this will cause a performance blow doing a table scan. Inside your select statement, select only desired columns that are needed for display in your UI.

As others have pointed our, do check your database column that its of type int or varchar, if the later you can cast your column as an int, or better create it as an int altogether.

Comment: It is still posting without any sequence.I just posted TaskId 127 and it comes right after TaskId 107

Comment: @mash when your run your query in database do you get the correct sort order?

Comment: @Mash also what happens when you sort the rows through your gridview? Is the order correct then?

Comment: So when i insert data using sql server,its works absolutely fine.So is there a problem with my stored procedure??

Comment: I tried running by stored procedure too,it works fine.so it must be something with my code-behind

Comment: @Mash just run the select statement with an order clause on your database and verify the results.